# Tracd creating Environment

Tags: tracd

I was trying to create a Tracd Environment using the following command :

trac-admin D:\My_Project initenv

I get an error saying

Import Error : No module named pkg_resources

What am I missing? I have installed Genshi and Python 2.5.2

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Read the [Trac wiki](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracOnWindows#using-installers). You need [setuptools](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/SetupTools), which you can download [here](http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c7.win32-py2.5.exe#md5=395a81d709766f3a0d6084964cb98b5a).